# Exit status 4 received for JSch exec channel

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I'm coding an app to manage some remote devices. I have trouble using JSch to restart dhcpdaemon. I do:

```
@Override
    public void createSession(String hostname) throws JSchException {
        this.session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
        this.session.setPassword(password);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }
 private final String RESTART_COMMAND = "/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart";
 public int reloadDHCPDaemon() throws IOException, JSchException, InterruptedException {
        int exitStatus = -1;
        String command = RESTART_COMMAND;

        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setPty(true);
        channel.setCommand(command);

        channel.connect();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        if (channel.isClosed() == true) {
            exitStatus = channel.getExitStatus();
            channel.disconnect();
        }
        return exitStatus;

    }
```

I'm getting 4 as an exit status no matter if the command ended successfully or not. The same code but with other commands, for example `cp` works fine. Can somone help me?

Comment: When you log into the remote server interactively and run "/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart", what exit code does it exit with?

Comment: Either 0 or 1 depending on my dhcpd.conf file.

Comment: And does the command work (does it restart the DHCP), when you run it with JSch? Does it print something?

Comment: It doesn't work. I can see dhcp status as not restarted (uptime didn't change). JSch just returns 4 as an exit code and thats all, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: I mean if the `isc-dhcp-server` prints something. Try to redirect it to a file.

Comment: I really wouldn't like to do that. I'm only interested in exit status rather then message.